# how to traverse a wijmo tree

Tags: jquery, tree, wijmo

I was wondering if anyone has ever worked with wijmo components?
What i am trying to do is to start from the root element of a wijmo tree, and traverse all the elements and return them as a tree structure.

thank you,
krizD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it would be to traverse the DOM using a recursive function on the li tags. Then turn it into JSON as a "tree object".

You can get the root level elements to begin your recursive function like so:

```
$("#tree").wijtree();

$("#tree > ul > li").each(function(){ yourRecursiveFunc(node) });
```

Comment: I haven't actually tested it yet, because I found another way of doing it, which is to inherit from wijtree and create my own functions which would get me all the nodes.
However I know that theoretically this answer should work.